# AttributeError: tensorflow has no attribute io

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, attributeerror, simpletransformers

I am trying to train a seq2seq model using simpletransformers library. While using the Seq2Seq model, I am constantly getting this error

```
import tensorflow as tf
from simpletransformers.seq2seq import Seq2SeqModel, Seq2SeqArgs

import logging
 model_args = {
"reprocess_input_data": True,
"overwrite_output_dir": True,
"max_seq_length": 50,
"train_batch_size": 16,
"num_train_epochs": 3,
"save_eval_checkpoints": False,
"save_model_every_epoch": False,
"evaluate_generated_text": True,
"evaluate_during_training_verbose": True,
"use_multiprocessing": False,
"max_length": 50,
"manual_seed": 42,}

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
transformers_logger = logging.getLogger("transformers")
transformers_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

 model = Seq2SeqModel(
"roberta",
"roberta-base",
"bert-base-uncased",from_tf=True,
 args=model_args,use_cuda=False)


AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'io'
```

tensorflow version == 2.11.0
python == 3.8.3

Comment: you can try `!pip install tensorflow-io` and then see

Comment: thanks for he help but this is not working

Comment: what is the platform you're using?

Comment: Platform? Using jupyter notebook

Comment: Can you should the complete stack traceback you get?